# Tinyslider vertical slide not working

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm useing tinyslider2 on a project and need to have the slider, slide vertical, which tinyslider should be able to.

> , and a direction toggle (vertical or horizontal).

but can't seem to get it to work.

```
var text_slider=new TINY.slider.slide('text_slider',{
            id:'slider',
            auto:4,
            resume:true,
            vertical: true,
            position:0,
            rewind:false,
            elastic:false,
            left:'button_down',
            right:'button_up'
        });

<div class="down" id="button_down" onclick="text_slider.move(-1)"></div>
<div class="up" id="button_up" onclick="text_slider.move(1)"></div>
```

It does not move up or down, unless I set position to 1> and then it slides to the bottom at once.... Am I doing something wrong, when trying to make it vertical slide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!! I found out, why it did'nt work... Forgot to put it inside a ul>li (was having divs inside.)